# C/C++ Can I use ODBC 3.x functions in an ODBC 2.x application?

Tags: c++, database, visual-c++, odbc

I have an old ODBC application which is an ODBC 2.x application (using ODBC 2.x functions). It works fine when I connect to ODBC 3.x drivers. But now, I would like use some of the ODBC 3.x functions in my application, such as `SQLBulkOperations`.

My question is, whether I need make extra changes if I want to call ODBC 3.x functions in my ODBC 2.x application? If yes, can you give more details?

Note, all the drivers I use is ODBC 3.x

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be ok doing this as the driver manager looks after all this and will already be mapping your ODBC 2 API calls to ODBC 3 ones in the driver.

It is possible you may need to call SQLSetEnvAttr to set (SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION) the version to 3 but I don't think so and you should hope not as it changes 1) ODBC 3.x codes for date, time, and timestamp 2) returns ODBC 3.x SQLSTATE codes.